# Hide android application icon after install

Tags: android

I've seen that there are some GPS application on Google apps where, after installation, the application will have no icon display yet will run services in the background.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Check out the responses on [this post](http://androidforums.com/developer-101/210047-hide-application-android-application-list.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For removing Application from Launcher just do not put these lines with main Activity in  `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

and if you want to remove it programatically then use [PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) for removing it from the Launcher as :

```
  ComponentName componentToDisable =
  new ComponentName("com.xxx.apptodisable",
  "com.xxx.apptodisable.LauncherActivity");

  getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(
  componentToDisable,
  PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
  PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: But when i remove the <intent-filter> i got an error.The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

Answer (score 4):

use this code

```
PackageManager p = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager(); 
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(),PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: I had used this method and open applcation when message receive menac in brodcast recerver i had open application but when i used this code to hide app and recever start activity it's crase that activity not found while without code when message receve it's perfectly open. can u help me?

Comment: This works for me... My app is not anymore visible in the launcher. Yet my service is still working in the background...This must be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

Best Way To Hide Application Icon From Launcher You Can Use `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>` In Your Manifest MainActivity

```
  <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

also add uses-feature

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just don't implement an Activity with a `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` category intent-filter, and that the Service receive boot broadcast.

Comment: but it will not open activity. i want to install aplication start acitivity also but hide app icon