# android hide app icon and make it visible

Tags: android, icons, hide, visible

I'm working on my app. there's two app, one should be hide. and open by another one. I try code like this in app A

```
        PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(getComponentName(), PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

and try to open app A by code

```
Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()
                        .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.hideicon");
                startActivity(intent);
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You'll need to provide more info about your problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solve my question . firstly you must hide your app icon by remove

```
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
```

second  you can add code in app B

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.hideicon");
              intent.setComponent(ComponentName
                  .unflattenFromString("com.example.hideicon/com.example.hideicon.MainActivity"));
              intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
              startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: did this work ? i tried but it gives exception android.content.ActivityNotFoundExceptio ..

Answer (score 1):

For hide app icon

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(Test.this,com.example.MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

For display app icon

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(Test.this, com.example.MainActivity.class);
p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: Hi  I try your code .It didn't work....i can't open it.it's called  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: you had change class name and other thing?

Answer (score 0):

It will not work since you have disabled the component and haven't enabled it before starting. To disable/enable it requires the permission.

Answer (score 0):

please check this link i hope its useful to you.

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715432/hide-android-application-icon-after-install)

remove launcher in manifest file from main acitivity.and programatically set it.